# MYSQL Syntax Error in DB Query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have the following error but I cant find the issue - can anyone else spot it - need another set of eyes:

Error near `'order, state) VALUES ('SAME',2,'1',10,1)'`

**DB Query:**

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO $table (brand_name, brand_id, cat_id, order, state) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
    $this->db->query($query, array($brand_name, $brand_id, $cat, $order ,$state));
```

Comment: Wow, that's weird!

I can't see the error. Whats the value of $table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Order is a reserved keyword, you need to wrap it in backticks or double quotes (depending on your database config): `order` or "order".

Answer (score 0):

add quotations '' around variables